# Access admin interface of Varnish using Docker (on Plesk)

Tags: docker, varnish, plesk, varnish-4

I'm trying to setup Varnish (varnish-4.0.5 revision 07eff4c29) using Docker on Plesk. This all seems to work just fine as I'm seeing HITS. The last hurdle I have to take is accessing Varnish from outside the container to clear the cache using our CMS. On another server I can access Varnish just fine, but this is without Plesk and Varnish version is 3.

To try and access I've tried several things. From a terminal on the server I telnet into the docker container as follows:

```
telnet 172.17.0.3 6082
```

To which Varnish responds:

```
107 59 
mrvwpbwcqkmesncevpdnuvfhssasmtob
```

Given secret key `a63b28f6-4346-4049-ee48-4942e8f00be1` I reply:

```
auth 59886f05927b7d4aa25ef7665c2895b29e8ccd4605ceeb3d98a511675bcd65ad
```

I have tried to respond  with every combination of "challenge 0x0a secret 0x0a challenge 0x0a" using a sha256 hash. But I cannot seem to be authenticated. I did verify I'm getting the same sha256 hash as the varnish examples of 3.0 documentation have, so I think I'm at least getting the correct hash for whatever information I test in.

How can I best debug this?

I'm doubting the secret I'm using. It is in /etc/varnish/secret (inside the container) but I'm not sure this is the actual file or setting Varnish looks at, even though varnish.params says: VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

I did find a related problem where it is suggested I should use varnishadm as the client (https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2015-August/024492.html). But varnishadm is not installed on the server an I have no permissions to install it either.